How can I automatically add followers to a Task based on the employees selected in a Many2many field?

I have a Many2many field x_studio_many2many_field_Cv65K in the project.task model, linked to hr.employee. This field allows selecting employees as "Performers" for a task. I want these selected employees to be automatically added as followers of the task when the field is updated, and the task is saved.
I tried the following code, which successfully adds employees as followers, but no notification emails are sent:
    new_followers = self.x_studio_many2many_field_Cv65K.mapped(
        'user_id.partner_id'
    ).filtered(
        lambda x: x.id not in self.message_partner_ids.ids
    ).ids        
    
    vals = [{
        'res_id': self.id, 
        'res_model': 'project.task',
        'partner_id': pid,  
    } for pid in new_followers]
    
    self.env['mail.followers'].create(vals)

How can I ensure that the followers are added and that notification emails are sent to them? Any suggestions on the correct approach or methods to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

This solution leverages Odoo's built-in functionality by using the mail.wizard.invite model, which is designed to handle both adding followers and sending email notifications smoothly.
Instead of directly creating records in the mail.followers model, which bypasses Odoo's notification mechanism, this method ensures that the in-built process is followed. By calling the add_followers() function on the mail.wizard.invite record, Odoo automatically handles all the necessary conditions, including notifying users via email invitations.
@api.constrains('x_studio_many2many_field_Cv65K')
def _constrains_performers(self):
    wizard = self.env['mail.wizard.invite'].sudo().create({
        'partner_ids': self.x_studio_many2many_field_Cv65K.mapped(
            'user_id.partner_id'),
        'send_mail': True,
        'res_id': self.id,
        'res_model': self._name
    })
    wizard.add_followers()


You can use the message_subscribe method to add followers to a recordset. Simply pass the list of res.partner recordset IDs as follows:
self.message_subscribe(partner_ids=partner_ids)

Here, partner_ids is a list of res.partner record IDs that you want to add as followers.

Thank you for the solution, I tried this one as well, however it does not work with the model 'project.task'.

You need to inherit the mail.thread model first for this method to work.
